# Which is the easiest way of drawing a shape using react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am buidling a mobile app (similar to GeoGebra), using react native and I need to draw some geometric shapes, preferably from an array of points. By searching online I have found out so many alternatives but those that I tried do not work for me (SVGs, react-polygon etc..), maybe because of some compatibility issues with the latest version of react native.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that there is a quite trivial way of doing it:

```
<Svg>
    <Polygon points = {[0,0,100,20,40,50]}/>
</Svg>
```

Just by installing react-native-svg, while I was looking for an external extension of react-native.